# jbehave run steps have exact filters match

Tags: jbehave

I am trying to run stories that have the exact filters match that specified on embedder

here is the embedder

```
embedder.useMetaFilters(asList("+us", "+smoke test"));
```

and the story

```
Scenario: verify scenario 1
Meta: @us @SmokeTest
Given do something 
When do something 
Then do something 

Scenario: verify scenario 2
Meta: @us
Given do something 
When do something 
Then do something
```

I need to run only scenario 1 but its keep run the 2 scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Groovy meta matcher is the best option for the provided story as it doesn't require story updates:

```java
embedder.useMetaFilters(asList("groovy: us && SmokeTest"));
```

http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html:

> As Groovy is an optional dependency, users wanting to use the Groovy Meta Matcher need to add it to the runtime classpath.